# Iframe wont respect login cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, iframe, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a very strange issue that i have been trying to debug for more then a week now.    I am out of ideas as to what the problem could be.    I am hoping someone here may have run into this same problem before and be able to give me an idea what the issue could be and how to fix it.

I a asp .net core 2.0 application.  It runs fine when hosted stand alone.

1. Main controller requires authentication.
2. Logs into Identity server 4.  (hybrid granttype)
3. Returns to application fetches data and displays it.

Now when i try and add this application as a plugin in the main application it doesnt work.  It actually loops around.   Plugins are displayed in the main application in an iFrame.

```
<iframe src="https://XXXXX" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

Watching the logs.  I can see it being forwarded to the Identity server logging returning to the plugin sight were i can see that it

```
OnSignedIn: IsAuthenticated = True
```

I can see that the plugin has an access token.  Then the loop starts.  It goes back to the identity server asks for access again and the whole thing continues endlessly.

What i can see that is diffrent between running standalone and running as a plugin is this line is missing in the log

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
```

I can also see in the headers on the requests that the Identity server returns the cookie headers and tells it to do a setcookie but it is never set.

Why is the cookie not set when in an Iframe?

What i have tried

```
 options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
 options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
```

Content-Security-Policy headers includes both the identity server, the plugin site and the main web application sites.

Why isnt the cookie being set?

## Plugin auth code.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";


            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
                options.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();                   
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = Configuration["ServiceSettings:IdentityServerEndpoint"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = Configuration["ServiceSettings:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ServiceSettings:secret"];
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("testapi");

            });
    }
```

## headers

```
 app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", Configuration["DefaultApplicationSettings:ContentSecurityPolicy"]);

            await next();
        });
```

## settings

```
 "DefaultApplicationSettings": {
"ContentSecurityPolicy": "default-src 'self' plugin webapp; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ webapp; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com/ webapp; frame-ancestors 'self' webapp"  },
```

Urls changed due to company privacy.

Comment: I have tried in chrome and edge.

Comment: Firefox says [Identity server login url] does not permit cross-origin framing  trying to find cowokers with other browsers to test.

Comment: I have added the headers for you not sure how useful it will be being that the urls needed to be changed.

Comment: This isnt javascript or ajax no i do not have that on the identityserver.  Nor am i getting Cors errors in the browser when running it as a plugin or as standalone

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a lot of searching one of my cowkers found a comment in the identity server 4 source code

[IdentityServerBuilderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/IdentityServerBuilderExtensions.cs#L47)

```
 // we need to disable to allow iframe for authorize requests
 cookie.Cookie.SameSite = AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
```

as soon as i changed

```
options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
```

to

```
options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
```

It worked.

> Indicates whether the browser should allow the cookie to be attached to same-site requests only (`SameSiteMode.Strict`) or cross-site requests using safe HTTP methods and same-site requests (`SameSiteMode.Lax`). When set to `SameSiteMode.None`, the cookie header value isn't set. Note that Cookie Policy Middleware might overwrite the value that you provide. To support OAuth authentication, the default value is SameSiteMode.Lax. For more information, see OAuth authentication broken due to SameSite cookie policy.

Why this works i am still not clear but it it works.

Comment: This works because when putting SaneSite to none, browser will send the login cookie with request made from iframe. If it's lax, browser will send the cookie if it's only a redirection to top level navigation URL. This is a mechanism introduced to mitigate CSRF attacks.

Comment: You saved my time @daimto. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't this open attack surface for CSRF ?

Comment: It worked for me too thanks. I'm using .Net Core 3 web application 
I added that code on StratUp.cs :where I added authentication cookie

Comment: It worked for me too, I am using .NET 5 and Okta with SAML.  in my Startup, where i add Saml i adjusted
```services.AddSaml2();```
to
```services.AddSaml2(cookieSameSite: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None);```